# cordova is not a valid task

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic2

I format my mac and set up ionic environment

1.install node.js

2.npm install -g cordova

3.npm install -g ionic@2.2.3

After that, `ionic serve -l` can run without error, but when I try build android `ionic cordova build android --prod` error coming out.
[image]

Ionic info:

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI:  You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
7.0.1

Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 2.1.3
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.11.3
Xcode version: Xcode 8.3.3 Build version 8E3004b
```

When I run `ionic serve -l`, also show this warning for me

[image]

Comment: Try out typing 'cordova -v in the new command promt. If it prompts for yes or no, select no option and try rerunning your command'

Comment: Try `ionic build android --prod` because in ionic CLI v2.2.3 cordova not supported

Comment: @Yuyang He were you able to bypass this error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Add the platforms that you want to target your app. We will add the 'ios' and 'android' platform.

```
$ cordova platform add android
```

If everything else is in place and you have already added all required resources then just type:

```
ionic cordova build android
```

If you face android resource issue then you can use this command:

```
ionic resources
```

and then rebuild it.It should work then.

Comment: cordova platform add android - This shows platform already added.
ionic cordova build android - This shows cordova is not a valid task

please help

Comment: @IrfanRaza what version are you using ?